# Is there an idiom that means something is "the best thing or better than other things"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means something is "the best thing or better than other things"? I am looking for a phrase that would look good in the introduction of an essay where I talk about the best marketing strategy used by companies nowadays. Can you think about anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ue ["optimal"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/optimal) as in "the optimal strategy" or the "optimal approach". That is a word, not an idiom, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an older phrase that might still apply, given your audience is at least 50 years old (in 2022), "it's the Cadillac of (insert competitive-market noun)". As in, "it's the Cadillac of reclining chairs."

Cadillac is a luxury car brand in the USA, known for soft floaty feeling rides and sometimes a lot of power. Generally admired by older people, starting around age 40.

As foreign cars have proven their dependability and value over the last 40 years there are more people that will take issue with a claim that your product is "the Cadillac" or apex choice, however that can be an opportunity to further interact with them and size up what they are looking for in a product. Be prepared for a light-hearted argument and don't take the stance that the Cadillac is the gold-standard of vehicles, it is all just marketing fluff after all. There are no absolutes; it's like arguing iPhone vs Android.

For reference, a 2012 article [Cadillac brand 100 years and still strong](https://www.cleveland.com/automotive/plaindealer/2012/03/cadillacs_brand_still_strong_as_it_starts_another_100_years.html)

Another tongue-in-cheek reference when referring to a car (since a Cadillac is a car you would not reference it in that marketplace) [Movie: Get Shorty - minivan test drive scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mohoyRj_VpU)